# Login with AD user inside a container who isn't in domain

Tags: docker, authentication, rdp, wine

I am currently looking for a way to connect inside a Docker with AD user without have to join the domain...

And Hello, i don't know why but it's deleted if i put it on first line...

Here some details:

- My user have a Windows Application need
- My user have no access to my host
- My user have access to some container who are running on my host.
- My host is inside the domain
- My host is running under CentOS 8

So the idea here was to put Wine inside a container, and connect in with RDP protocole just like this container do:

https://hub.docker.com/r/scottyhardy/docker-wine/

To be honest, this Docker perfectly fit to what i need, but i have to connect inside with a local user...And i need to be able to know "Who connect" inside this Docker...So i can't allow everyone to connecte with just single local user, and create local user for each user isn't a great solution...

So what i need is that my user use their AD account to connect inside this Docker, but since it is a Docker, who will be short-lived...I don't want it to join my domain each time a container is created (And i don't even know if AD would allow this honestly)

Is there a way to achieve it ?

thank for your help ! (And sorry for my english)

EDIT: I have found a way to do it, but it required to execute container with --priviliged flag, and then to install SSSD and configure it inside the Docker :

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/using_containerized_identity_management_services/configuring-the-sssd-container-to-provide-identity-and-authentication-services-on-atomic-host

Comment: Dear, your question is not concise for readers to answer and contains many sentences that could be ignored, I use docker but I need to read your question many times to undrestand... Good luck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.